# How do I send and receive sensor data using Arduino and Xbee pro 900HPs

Tags: arduino, xbee

I've been trying to send and receive data on Arduino using the Xbee pro 900HP but I can't get them to communicate. Does anybody have any good information or guides on how to achieve this?

At the moment I have two Arduino Nanos wired for serial communication to the Xbee pro modules.

the code for the transmitter:

```
int y = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(y);
  y++;
}
```

The code for the receiver:

```
int x = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("starting...");
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available() == 0);
  int data = Serial.read() - '0';
  
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(data);
  x++;
  Serial.flush();
}
```

please let me know about anything that could possibly be wrong im losing my mind over this and im assuming its something simple im overlooking.

Comment: The question is a little bit too broad to be solved easily. Take it in the chat maybe? And check this one out: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/xbee-pro-900hp-arduino-to-arduino-wireless/361524

Comment: I have updated the initial post to be more specific. Sorry for being to broad.

Comment: I might be confused but your While statement with ";" seems strange. Try it with brackets "{ }"

Comment: having the brackets and the ; doesnt seem to change anythign

Comment: Try copying the example I posted. See if it works. You have some strange type casting and string modifications: int data = Serial.read() - '0'

Comment: I unfortunately dont have a second computer to actually have them communicate like that

Comment: Head over here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering

Comment: debug by replacing all code in `loop()` with something like this pseudo code `if (Serial.available() == 0) { led off } else {led on; data = Serial.read();}`

Comment: @jsotola it would appear that that does not work like the LED does not turn on

Comment: I can give you a couple of minutes in the chat.

Comment: put a 10 ms delay in your transmit code ... see if that makes a diff

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is a bit unclear. Is it two Arduinos talking to over an XBee link or is it something else? If you have two Arduinos talking to eachother try making your software to work with just the two devices talking via UART first, no XBee.

You mentioned Arduino Nano. This could be problematic since a Nano could be a 5V logic device and the XBee might bee a 3.3V logic device, you need to sort that out first. When that is good you should use the XTCU software that Digi has, to configure the modules. Setup the baudrates and set it to AT commands (coordinator?) before using them as UART bridges.